# why mysql format function work something wrong with set action?

Tags: mysql

First ,  the columns is create like that :

```
 `avg_price` float NOT NULL default 0,
 `total_price` float NOT NULL default 0,
 `count` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
```

and when I execute  the action  like that :

```
update `member`  set avg_price = format(`total_price`/`count`,2) where id =  971473
```

the result doesn't  work with my expection.  when the `total_price` is 9003 and the count is 4 ,   The avg_price was expect to  update to  just like 2250.75 ,but it just update to 2.

could someone tell me why this happen, thanks a  lot  .

Comment: what would you like to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon explained what you should be doing, but failed to explain why you only get the value of 8.

`format(8765.33,2)` returns `'8,765.33'` as a string. Mysql then tries to convert this string to a number. During the conversion mysql processes the string from left character by character as long as the value can be interpreted as a number. Comma has no place in a number, therefore mysql stops processing the string right there and returns the value it could interpret as a number - which is 8.

If the number to be formatted is less than 1000, then `format()` does not place a comma into the string, therefore mysql can convert the string to a number. I think you just want to round the number, so use the [round()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function instead:

```
round(`total_price`/`count`,2)
```

Also consider using the [decimal data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) for storing any prices, since it stores the exact value as opposed to float.

The rest is explained by Gordon.

Comment: The `round()` function can't actually do what it promises if the result is stored as FLOAT.

Comment: @EJP this is why I added that the OP should consider using decimal data type.

Comment: So you should say so in your answer, instead of recommending something that won't work.

Comment: @EJP . . . `round()` will still *round* the number.  It gets converted again in the storage as a float.  But it seems like the closest logic for what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

1. `format()` produces a string, possibly with commas in it. There's nothing that guarantees a `format()` result can be stored into a FLOAT.
2. You should not *try* to control decimal precision of FLOAT values. FLOATs don't have decimal places, they have binary places, so any such attempt is doomed to failure.
3. You shouldn't be using FLOAT in the first place. Never use floating-point for money. You should hold currency values as DECIMAL, not FLOAT, for example DECIMAL(10,2). That would solve the entire problem at a stroke.
4. As `avg_price` is computable from `total_price` and `count`, there is a strong case to say that it shouldn't be a column at all, and that this is a violation of 3NF. You can get it any time you want it, via `select total_price/count as avg_price`. You may want to format it at that stage. Not in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what the issue is with this?

```
update `member`
    set avg_price = 8765.33
    where id =  971473;
```

What is `format()` supposed to be doing?  You have declared `avg_price` to be a `float`, so there is no need to use a function that returns a string.

Comment: sorry, I  just want my  question  become a little  simple.   I have   completed  my question now .